# display <div> with embedded <Link> inline with surrounding text

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have some text content that I am conditionally replacing with a link (#Hashtags and @mentions) using `react-string-replace`.

This is my string replace code direct from `react-string-replace` documentation.

```
content = reactStringReplace(content, /#(\w+)/g, (match, i) => (
                    <div className="d-inline">
                        &nbsp;
                        <Link key={match + i} to={`/hashtags/${match}`}>
                            #{match}
                        </Link>
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                ));
```

`Link` is a react-bootstrap component which in this case links to the matching hashtag.

Without the `<div> &nbsp;` the hashtags render without surrounding spaces. This also means that two adjacent hashtags render with a double space.

Is there a way to display this div as inline text? i have tried `className="d-inline"` and `className="d-block"`

Comment: Instead of a space, why don't you make use of a margin like so, <div className="ml-2">.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution using your similar approach:

```
.hashtag:before {
  content: " ";
}

.hashtag:after {
  content: " ";
}

<>
  Hello
  <Link className="hashtag" to={`...`}>
    #foo
  </Link>
  <Link className="hashtag" to={`...`}>
    #bar
  </Link>
  <Link className="hashtag" to={`...`}>
    #hello
  </Link>
  World
</>
```

This way, we do not render html entities, we render spaces so the double spaces will not occur due to the default CSS value of `white-space: normal`

[image: Edit youthful-kapitsa-lqo3q]

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values